# TypeError: Cannot read property 'schoolName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, nodemailer

So I'm trying to delete a form that is filled in by a user, the user when submitted is tied into the user.id however when I try to call some of the user properties I get an undefined error.

Here is my route:

```
// delete competition form
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/delete/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  CompetitionForm.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, competition, user){
    req.flash('success_msg', `The competition form removed successfully!`);
    res.redirect('/dashboard');

    const output = `
      <h3>Competition Form Deletion</h3>
      <p>Hello ${user.schoolName},<p>
      <p>We are emailing you to make you aware that your competition form has been deleted from our records!<p>
      <br>
      <p>- POL – Puerto Rico</>
    `;

    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
      // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
          port: 587,
          auth: {
            user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
            pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
          }
        });
      } else {
        transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
          port: 587,
          auth: {
            user: 'qkkvnabtziufbksa@ethereal.email',
            pass: 'A4W9HF2WbhAav263VM',
          }
        });
      }
      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.GLOBAL_EMAIL || 'ben@benbagley.co.uk', // sender address
        to: `${user.email}`, // list of receivers
        subject: 'Competition Form Deletion | Poetry Out Loud', // Subject line
        html: output // html body
      };
      // send mail with defined transport object
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
        }

        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

If any other code is needed here, do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Do all users have the schoolName property? Try inspecting/logging the user that throws an error. Something like `${user.schoolName || ''}` will insert an empty string if you want to avoid having the error. But that doesn't actually fix the issue.

Comment: @Shilly All users enter a school name on initial registration.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason that schoolName isn't arriving at the server. Do you check in the form that the sent schoolName is not just a space or empty field? Hence just log the user object you receive to check why that property isn't on the user object at the time of the error.

Comment: Here are the full routes https://gist.github.com/benbagley/45aa6d37d56b532c9b1adce4d1bef18a The form uses `competitions.schoolName` but I would like to get this working off the user as I need to be able to send the email to the user using the email they use to login. @Shilly

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing means that `user` is undefined when it is called.  Try placing a `debugger;` somewhere in the function `function(err, competition, user){...}` and running the call with dev tools open.  When it stops you should be able to use the call stack and find your problem.